# Permission to a user in a subfolder inside a folder to which he does not have access

Tags: windows, permissions, file-access, administration

I have a Windows Server 2012 and I need to configure the privileges to a group called DP_Preven. This is the scenario:

- I have a folder called X where only a few groups have access, inside that folder there is another one called Y.
- I want group DP_Preven to access with full privileges to the folder Y, but with no privileges or just read privilege to the folder X.
- Inside X folder there are more subfolders, but DP_Preven should not have access to those folders.

I need to know which privileges I should give to DP_Preven in X.

Comment: I have tried to give read and list permisions to DP_PREVEN in X and full control in Y. but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use the *Advanced Security Settings*, where you can see the inheritance options, too.

Your `DP_Preven` needs:

- Allow *Read & Execute* to folder `X\` in order to traverse to `Y\`
- Allow *Modify* to `Y\*`
- since `Z\` doesn't inherit permissions from `X\`, there's no need for additional Deny.

Here, the Principal `DP_Preven` permissions for `F\` & `file` are inherited from `Y\`:

```
               Access       Inher.  Applies to

X\             Read & exec  None    This folder only
├── Y\         Modify       None    This, subf., files
|   ├── F\     Modify       X\Y\    This, subf., files
│   └── file   Modify       X\Y\    N/A
└── Z\         ---          ---     ---
```

The *Modify* is better than *Full control* as it doesn't allow deleting *self* i.e. folder `Y\`.

If `Z\` had Allow permission inherited from `X\` or its parents, then you need to either disable inheritance or add a *Deny* that always overwrites any *Allow*, but I *This folder only* easier to manage, since you don't have to remember to change the settings for every new subfolder separately.